# Headers are repeating when exporting Crystal Report to .csv format

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio to develop a crystal report. I create the application in Visual Studio and then upload the file in some other application where when exporting in .csv, the headers are repeating for every data row.

I googled this and one solution I got was this that under the File Menu, I have to select the export option and for .csv i have to select Isolate page/report section.
But i can't find the export option under the file menu in visual studio.

I am using SAP crystal report plugin in visual studio for development purpose.

Comment: If you are using Crystal Report Viewer, the export button can be found on the toolbar in the viewer as well.  If nobody else answers today, I can check it out later today when I have access to a computer with Visual Studio installed.

Comment: @R.McMillan No, Im using SAP crystal reports, version for Visual Studio. Its a plugin. When I open a crystal report from visual studio, all options reĺated to it can be seen under Extensions -》 Crystal Reports. And my main issue is that my .csv is repeating headers. If there is any other way to get that fixed then please let me know.Thanks.

Comment: When you execute a crystal report in your application, the viewer I'm referring to is used to view the report at run-time.  The export button you are looking for is found on the toolbar in this viewer.

Comment: @R.McMillan no, Im talking about the export button from this solution https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1817212 . It says, Open the report in Crystal Reports designer.

Under the menu "File", select "Export - Export Report"

In the "Export" window, select the format "Separated Values (CSV)", and click "OK"

In the "Separated Values Export Options" window, check the option "Isolate Report/Page sections"

Comment: I guess I should explain that there is more than one way to access that Export option you are trying to use.  You can use the File menu as instructed in your link, you can use the export report button on the toolbar in your designer, or you can use the export report button on the toolbar in the report viewer.  Since your VS plugin doesn't have the export option under the File menu, I was suggesting you use the export report button that is found on the viewer as an alternative.  I apologize for not explaining it better in my earlier comments.

Comment: @R.McMillan but in my application there is no such option such as isolate report/page sections in the viewer. It works well for excel but when exported in csv the header repeats for every data row. Is there other work around to get this fixed ?